# How to save data in cakephp 3 with saving to joinTable

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to php frameworks and I've started to learn cakephp few days ago, but even after reading cakephp cookbook about saving belongsToMany associations I still don't know how to implement it in my situation.

I have three tables:

**clients:**
id | firstname | lastname | phone | email

**interests:**
id | text | comment | status_id | created_at

**clients_interests:**
client_id | interest_id

Models and entities were baked so I don't think it's something wrong there, but here is the code:
**ClientsTable.php**

```
class ClientsTable extends Table
{            
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('clients');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsToMany('Interests', [
            'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'interest_id',
            'joinTable' => 'clients_interests'
        ]);
    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmptyString('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->scalar('firstname')
            ->maxLength('firstname', 64)
            ->requirePresence('firstname', 'create')
            ->allowEmptyString('firstname', false);

        $validator
            ->scalar('middlename')
            ->maxLength('middlename', 64)
            ->allowEmptyString('middlename');

        $validator
            ->scalar('lastname')
            ->maxLength('lastname', 64)
            ->requirePresence('lastname', 'create')
            ->allowEmptyString('lastname', false);

        $validator
            ->scalar('phone')
            ->maxLength('phone', 24)
            ->requirePresence('phone', 'create')
            ->allowEmptyString('phone', false)
            ->add('phone', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table']);

        $validator
            ->email('email')
            ->allowEmptyString('email');

        return $validator;
    }

    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['phone']));

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

**InterestsTable.php**

```
class InterestsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('interests');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Statuses', [
            'foreignKey' => 'status_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Clients', [
            'foreignKey' => 'interest_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'client_id',
            'joinTable' => 'clients_interests'
        ]);
    }


    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmptyString('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->scalar('text')
            ->maxLength('text', 128)
            ->requirePresence('text', 'create')
            ->allowEmptyString('text', false);

        $validator
            ->scalar('comment')
            ->maxLength('comment', 128)
            ->allowEmptyString('comment');

        $validator
            ->date('created_at')
            ->requirePresence('created_at', 'create')
            ->allowEmptyDate('created_at', false);

        return $validator;
    }


    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['status_id'], 'Statuses'));

        return $rules;
    }


    public function getAll($id)
    {
        $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
        $results = $connection
            ->execute('SELECT i.*, s.name status_name, s.classname status_classname FROM interests i INNER JOIN clients_interests ci ON ci.interest_id=i.id AND ci.client_id=:client_id INNER JOIN statuses s ON i.status_id=s.id ORDER BY created_at DESC;', ['client_id' => $id])
            ->fetchAll('assoc');
        return $results;
    }
}
```

**ClientsInterestsTable.php**

```
class ClientsInterestsTable extends Table
{            
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('clients_interests');
        $this->setDisplayField('client_id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey(['client_id', 'interest_id']);

        $this->belongsTo('Clients', [
            'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Interests', [
            'foreignKey' => 'interest_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }


    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['client_id'], 'Clients'));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['interest_id'], 'Interests'));

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Client entity - **Client.php**

```
class Client extends Entity
{         
    protected $_accessible = [
        'firstname' => true,
        'middlename' => true,
        'lastname' => true,
        'phone' => true,
        'email' => true
    ];
}
```

Interest entity - **Interest.php**

```
class Interest extends Entity
{          
    protected $_accessible = [
        'text' => true,
        'comment' => true,
        'status_id' => true,
        'created_at' => true,
        'clients_interest' => true,
        'status' => true
    ];
}
```

ClientsInterests entity - **ClientsInterests.php**

```
class ClientsInterest extends Entity
{

    protected $_accessible = [
        'client' => true,
        'interest' => true
    ];
}
```

And then in my controller I get all the data from a form. Interest entity after patchEntity() gets all its data besides client data for joinTable. And after save method new interest in **interests** table is created but there is no new row in **clients_interests** table. I've tried a lot of things from stackoverflow but it didn't work because I can't understand the mechanism of saving associated data even after reading the manual. Could anyone explain me in simple words how to save belongsToMany associated data?
Here is the code of my save method in **InterestsController.php:**

```
public function add()
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['ajax', 'post']);
        $this->response->withDisabledCache();

        $interest = $this->Interests->newEntity();
        $interest = $this->Interests->patchEntity($interest, $this->request->getData(), 
            ['associated'=>['Clients._joinData']]
        );       

        if($this->Interests->save($interest)) {
            $result = ['error' => null, 'error_text' => 'SUCCESSFUL'];
        } else {
            $result = ['error' => null, 'error_text' => 'ERRORS ERRORS ERRORS'];
        }

        $result = ['error' => null, 'error_text' => 'ERRORS ERRORS ERRORS'];
        $this->set('result', $result);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['result']);
    }
```

And in my template I use this input for getting client_id:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->control('clients.0.client_id', ['hidden', 'type'=>'text','id'=>'client-id', 'class'=>'form-control']); ?>
```

Request data looks like this: [request data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ1Rt.png)

And Interest entity after patchEntity() looks like this: [Interest entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iohL0.png)

Comment: I think you don't have the correct data in your request. Can you show it to us? Have you seen the exemple "Converting BelongsToMany Data" in "Saving Data" (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html) ? It may show you how to construct your request array.

Comment: @proprit I updated my question and added screenshots from the debugger. I read there how should look like the input for associated data for correctly marshaling after patchEntity() but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add an 'interest', I think your request data should look differently.

Here is an example, but sorry, I haven't tested it, it's made so you get the idea : you have to tell CakePHP you want to create a Interest entity, and inside add a Client information (just like in the "Converting BelongsToMany Data" in "Saving Data" of [book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html))).

```
$data = [
_csrfToken => "...",
'interests' => [
    'text' => 'texttext',
    'comment' => '',
    'created_at' => '2019-01-10',
    'status_id' => 2,
    'clients' => [
        '_ids' => [0],
   ]
];
```

Personally, I learnt a lot looking at the requests generated through the Form Helper from the automatically baked templates.

Comment: Thanks for reply. All in all I fixed my input and set its name to clients._ids.0 But another problem was that either bake function or my db creation in phpmyadmin caused incorrect work of models and entitties that were baked. I still don't know what was the cause of this problem, but I started my project from scratch again and have used pure sql commands for creating databases instead of phpmyadmin and then have baked all things and now it works like a charm:) Thanks for a one more time